# Qt Designer misaligning items correctly configured

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, alignment, qt-designer

I'm trying to display some items in Qt Designer, but I'm being unable to do it because despite I correctly place them in the .ui, when I compile and run the code, the items are misplaced:

[image: Left is Qt Designer, Right is what I get]

You can notice by the images above that what I want is in the left side: the four items inside the QStackedWidget perfectly aligned with other items, but what I get is what is in the right part: all four items inside the QStackedWidget are misaligned.

I tried to manipulate the variables related to margin etc. as much as possible but I simply can't understand why the app is showing something different from what was programmed. Any tip on how to solve this problem?

---

*UPDATE*

Adding the following image to help in comments of a given answer below:

[image: Labels and line edits size fixed]

---

*UPDATE*

The .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>306</width>
    <height>229</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>306</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>306</width>
    <height>229</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbUpdate">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Update</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="2">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>40</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="3">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbFullUpdate">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Full update</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbSingleFile">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Single file</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>89</width>
          <height>17</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="swInfo">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>1</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Version ID:</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="2">
         <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
          <item row="0" column="0">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbVersionIDIncrease1">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>31</width>
              <height>31</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>^</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="1">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbVersionIDIncrease2">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>31</width>
              <height>31</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>^</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item row="0" column="2">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbVersionIDIncrease3">
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>31</width>
              <height>31</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>^</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="leID">
          <property name="text">
           <string>33.4550.1</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
         <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>20</width>
            <height>40</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <property name="sizeConstraint">
         <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item row="0" column="1">
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="leServerAddress">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>186</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>186</width>
            <height>16777215</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string/>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true"/>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Server path:</string>
          </property>
          <property name="buddy">
           <cstring>leServerAddress</cstring>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="1">
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lePathToSave">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>186</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>186</width>
            <height>16777215</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>/mmcblk0p2/</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Path to save:</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Equipment IP:</string>
      </property>
      <property name="buddy">
       <cstring>leEquipmentIP</cstring>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="leEquipmentIP">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>186</width>
        <height>33</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>186</width>
        <height>33</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>10.1.25.10</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>leEquipmentIP</tabstop>
  <tabstop>pbUpdate</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by putting a horizontal spacer between the labels and the QLineEdits (strange that I remember trying this solution before without success). Anyway that doesn't answer my question on *why* is this happening.

Comment: I forgot to ask - what kind of layouts are you using inside the stacked widget for pages? In my answer its Form Layout (in picture for "page" item)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why the two rows of widgets in the middle should line up with the outer ones, given that they are not part of the same layout.

This should be more obvious if the text in the bottom lable is made longer:

[image: snapshot from qt designer]

So it seems your conclusion is backwards: it's actually the *compiled* version that is correct, and the Qt Designer version which needs further explanation. But without being able to test the real ui file, it's hard to say much more than that.

**UPDATE**:

If the maximum/minimum size is reset to the default for `MainWindow` and `leEquipmentIP`, you can more easily see what's going on.

When the window is resized horizontally, the spacing between the labels and the line-edits changes at different rates. So there is a critical width for the window where the line-edits will be perfectly aligned. For me, this width is 303 pixels, but the exact value may depend on things like the window type, current widget style, current window decoration, etc.

This is probably enough to explain why Qt Designer may sometimes display things differently. For instance, on my system, I use the Docked Window interface mode, and so forms are displayed as MDI windows. This means they get a different window decoration to top-level windows (such as Qt Designer itself), and so their external frame dimensions may be slightly different.

Comment: well, that is an interesting observation, although it still leaves open the question on why the running app is shown different then what is put in the .ui file (IOW in general I would agree with what you noticed, but I don't see why the compiled version would show differently then what is in the .ui once it should maintain, AFAIK, what was programmed there and there it is aligned).

Comment: @Momergil. The only reason why the question is open is because you still have not posted the actual ui file. I see from one of your other comments that are using fixed sizes for some of the widgets. It's details like that that can make all the difference.

Comment: for some reason I forgot I could ctrl+c /ctrl+v the code of the .ui instead of the file ^^ I updated the question. Thanks for you time.

Comment: @Momergil. See my updated answer for some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Form Layout (having two columns like in form)

**Update:**

I used form layouts for above and below part. In the middle there is stacked widget.
The right side of line inputs is aligned properly, also the left side is also aligned properly. I achieved this by setting all margins of stacked widget to 0 and form layouts margins were already at 0. 
Also I used vertical layout for whole form, this was necessary for proper alignment of three layouts together.
The problem is how to align that part between end of labels and start of line edits. I think this is not possible without hacking the min/max size of labels or whatever is on the left.

Maybe some change in design if possible would be better than to hack the (middle) alignment between different layouts (which I think is not possible).

[image]

Update 2:

Ok I took your ui file, placed in my QtCreator test project and the result is good - I do not have the problem of croped line edits as you show in your Updated screenshot. Maybe there is some residual resizing of whole window - what happen if you resize the window. Whatever I am doing I cannot trigger the same behaviour - the line edits are properly aligned all the time.

The remaining questions are - what is your QtCreator version, Qt version, OS.
Mine is QtCreator 3.3.2 Qt 5.4.1 Kubuntu 14.04

[image]

Comment: Well actually, in your example, you misplaced the position of the StackedWidget: not all widgets are inside it, but only the "Server path" and "Path to save" labels and the two correspondent QLineEdits. If I put all the widgets inside the QStackedWidget, then it would work fine as in your images. (notice the position of the two arrows in the left side of my image)

Comment: oh sorry I wasnt reading the question properly..
maybe you can place the other stuff also in another stacked widgets to get the same alignment, I will try update my answer

Comment: I updated the answer.. I agree with ekhumoro.. I think I said the same thing (I havent noticed that answer when I updated this one)..

Comment: thanks for the update. Actually you made an interesting point: the line edits were size fixed, but the labels were not. I now changed the .ui to make the labels also size-fixed and now the widgets are misaligned in a different way! (I'll update my question with an image on how it is this way)